# Stopping/Pausing avplayer created in tableview cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I am working on a video feed app with tableview.

I create `AVPlayer` object in tableview cell subclass and assing playitem to it in cellforitem. Everything is working good.

My problem is that I want to stop video on `viewDidDisappear` but I can't access tableview cell subclass' AvPlayer object to stop it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
   if let cell = $0 as? PostsWithVideoCustom , let player = cell.player { // assuming it's optional 
      // stop it here 
   }
}
```

Comment: I am having Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected PostsWithVideoCustom but found PostsWithPhotoCustom: file

Comment: I have multiple cell classes I guess we should check if only PostsWithVideoCustom is visible or not first ??